# move second last column to first using awk

Tags: awk

I would like do the following using awk:

The file use tab as field separator

Example of my input with the header and the first row of data

```
"Column1" "Column2" "Column3" "Column4" "Column5" 

  "a1"      "b2"      "c3"       "d4"      "e5"
```

Desired output

```
"Column4" "Column1" "Column2" "Column3"  "Column5" 

  "d4"      "a1"      "b2"      "c3"       "e5"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Just need to arrange the fields in the desired order:

```
awk '{print $4, $1, $2, $3, $5}' your-file
```

Comment: This only works for the first row. For second row and onwards, there is no data in column $4.